# Error when creating android project on eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have been struggling with eclipse for about a month now .I deleted eclipse software even booted my pc thinking it have have confilicts with my other software.Even my teacher couldnt help me to fix this. Every time i try to create an android projects i get a lot of error from the start .Appcompact shows up with error .I found here people giving advices i did all of that but nothing has worked for me .

**On console :**

```
C:\Users\mm\Desktop\workspaceandroid\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.

C:\Users\mm\Desktop\workspaceandroid\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.

C:\Users\mm\Desktop\workspaceandroid\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
```

**when i check the error section it shows :**

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 75 Android AAPT Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\mm\Desktop\workspaceandroid\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'   Testapp     Build path  Build Path Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    Testapp     Unknown Java Problem
```

Please any one can help me fix this problem , i couldnt advance on my projects because of it.I would really apreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using `AppCompat.ActionButton` in style? You should increase the target API level

Comment: I just seen a person saying that if he put an API 14 as a minimun sdk he wont get a problem i'm downloading it now and i hope it can fix my problem

Comment: I mean i didnt even start a project i didnt touch nothing i let everything by default except when it comes to choose with what sdk to compile.

Comment: I did all that and still doesnt work !

Comment: still doesnt work  it shows this : Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
[2014-12-31 20:31:43 - Ma] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;

Comment: now the error that shows R cannot be solved to variable what should i do ?

Comment: did it work?? have you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do not know so i will just post this.. fyi: i have not specifically experienced this type of error, but more like it..

**1** : delete the `android-support-v4.jar` in your project and copy the `appcompat_v7`'s rather

**2** : Delete the all the files in the bin folder of the `appcompat_v7` and clean and build and restart (if this doesn't work at the 1st instance, disable build automatically-[by clicking the project on your eclipse], and redo the no2 and save and restart eclipse, and build save, and restart..)

**3** : right click on your `appcompat_v7` project goto build path then configure build path 
then java build path and to the tab order and export and uncheck all the libs there the ones ending with .jar ... if you do not see .jar files then (uncheck android private libraries)(goes with the condition - that's a hard guess because on my project its checked)

**4** : if you have other libraries then follow number 2(and 3) on them (3 is optional)

**5** : if none of them are working check if there's some update on the adt or anything that can be updated

*Always clean rebuild and restart eclipse okay.. Hope it helps*

Answer (score 0):

You should open the `project.properties` file from `android-support-v7-appcompat` and change the target api level to target=android-21.

Don't forget to clean the workspace after that using Project --> Clean...

Comment: Now that i put API 14 as a minimun appompact doesnt show but the problem now when i try to lunch the hello world then eclipse shows error on the app and say C:\Users\mm\Desktop\workspaceandroid\MY\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:AppBaseTheme'.

Comment: Are the xml files in the folder named values_v14?